# how to assign output of find into array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In linux shell scripting I am trying to set the output of find into an array as below

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=($(find . -type -f))
```

but it give error as -type should contain only one character. can anybody tell me where is the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Just remove - sign before f. `arr=($(find . -type f))`

Comment: Beware of filenames containing whitespace.

Comment: But you still need to consider choroba's point, which is 100% right: filenames with spaces will be broken into several array items.

Comment: yes that exactly right now, so how can I solve that

Comment: There is a way simpler than @jaybee 's answer. Simply do `IFS=$'\n' arr=($(find . -type f))`. `echo "${arr[X]}"` will display the Xth member of the array correctly even if there are spaces in the name

Comment: Yeah, brilliant!! :) I remember seeing somewhere advices about _not_ modifying the shell's IFS semi-permanently, for various reasons, but doing it here for just this one command is flawless. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `bash` 4, the `readarray` command can be used along with process substitution.

```
readarray -t arr < <(find . -type f)
```

Properly supporting *all* file names, including those that contain newlines, requires a bit more work, along with a version of `find` that supports `-print0`:

```
while read -d '' -r; do
    arr+=( "$REPLY" )
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
listoffiles=$(find . -type f)
nfiles=$(echo "${listoffiles}" | wc -l)
unset myarray
for i in $(seq 1 ${nfiles}) ; do
    myarray[$((i-1))]=$(echo "${listoffiles}" | sed -n $i'{p;q}')
done
```

Because you cannot rely on the Bash automatic array instanciation through the `myarr=( one two three )` syntax, because it treats the same way all whitespaces (including spaces) it sees within its parentheses. So you have to handle the resulting multiline variable `listoffiles` kindof manually, what I do in the above script.

`echo` without the `-n` option prints a trailing newline at the very end of the variable, but that's fine in our case because `find` doesn't (you may check this with `echo -n "${listoffiles}"`).

And I use **sed** to extract the relevant i^th line, with the `$i` being interpreted by the shell before being given to **sed** as the first character of its own script.

Comment: Bash doesn't treat spaces the same way at all. It just uses the global variable Internal Field Separator ($IFS) to determine which characters are used to separate fields. By default, its value is "spac tab newline" (`$' \t\n'`) but it can be remapped to any value you want. If you change its value to only `$'\n'`, bash will process the output of find line by line and will not count spaces as different fields